# How to modify the number of articles displayed on the homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, product-list, rwd-theme, cms-block

I have a question regarding the CMS pages of the Magento RWD theme.
I use the version 1.9.2.4 of Magento.

1- I added blocks and templates to call the categories in the "Madison Island" pages of CMS.

### Here are the blocks I added:

```
   {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" column_count="4" product_count="4" template="catalog/product/cms-home-category-slide.phtml"}}
```

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" column_count="4" product_count="4" template="catalog/product/cms-home-category-slide.phtml"}}
```

I also tried for example  `product_count="4"` or `limit_count="4"`but it didn't work.

2- I could check that the blocks in in WOMEN and MEN I added in "Madison Island" were displayed in the front end.

Here is a [sreenshot](http://www.fascinate.click/media/wysiwyg/Madison-Island.png) of the front end.

3- But the number of items displayed is the one written in System > `Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Frontend` , and not the number written in the blocks.

Here is a [screenshot](http://www.fascinate.click/media/wysiwyg/Frontend.PNG) of the number displayed in the frontend.

4- I want to display the number of items as I wrote it in the {{block .....}} . How could I do that?

Comment: Paste the code from the file cms-home-category-slide.phtml and also try changing product_count to products_count.

Comment: I created the cms-home-category-slide.phtml  from the magento default template list.phtml    . Where do you paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

What I recently did worked for me and that was in your `cms-home-category-slide.phtml` search for the grid mode and edit it with your needs like bellow. The column count is the number of columns and the $i=X is the number of products, in my case 4. So if you take 8 you get 2 columns instead.

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?> //HERE YOU ENTER THE AMOUNT OF COLUMNS YOU WANT
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php 
    $_productId = $_product->getId();?>
    <?php if($i == 4) break; ?> //THIS IS THE NUMBER OF PRODUCTS
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid row">
    <?php endif ?>
        <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-3" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/product">
....
```